# cmake not adding needed -fopenmp to linker command

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp

I'm building a program which is mostly Fortran, but includes a C++ interface library. This is a cmake project, and you can even find the specific branch on github [here](https://github.com/REOptimize-Systems/openfast/tree/static-openfast-cmake-obj-libs). I'm building on Linux using cmake 3.25.1

My issue is that there is a cmake option to build with OpenMP. The full CMakeLists.txt for the C++ library is shown below:

```
#
# Copyright 2016 National Renewable Energy Laboratory
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

if (${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "3.12.0")
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS C HL)
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)

include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDES})
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDES})
include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/openfast-library/src/)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules/openfoam/)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/modules/supercontroller/)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})

add_library(openfastcpplib
  src/OpenFAST.cpp 
  src/SC.cpp
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:openfastlib_common_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:openfast_prelib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:maplib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:nwtcbaselib_obj> 
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:nwtcsyslib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:nwtclibs_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ifwlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:fvwlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:uaaerolib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:afinfolib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:aeroacoustics_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:aerodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:aerodyn14lib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:servodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:elastodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:beamdynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:subdynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:hydrodynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:orcaflexlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:extptfm_mckflib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:openfoamtypeslib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:foamfastlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:scdataextypeslib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:scdataexlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:feamlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:moordynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:icedynlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:icefloelib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:openfast_postlib_obj>
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:versioninfolib_obj>
)
set_property(TARGET openfastcpplib PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
target_link_libraries(openfastcpplib
openfast_prelib_obj
maplib_obj
nwtclibs_obj
nwtcsyslib_obj
nwtcbaselib_obj
ifwlib
fvwlib
uaaerolib
afinfolib
aeroacoustics
aerodynlib
aerodyn14lib
servodynlib
elastodynlib
beamdynlib
subdynlib
hydrodynlib
orcaflexlib
extptfm_mckflib
openfoamtypeslib
foamfastlib
scdataextypeslib
scdataexlib
feamlib
moordynlib
icedynlib
icefloelib
openfast_postlib
versioninfolib
${HDF5_C_LIBRARIES}
${HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES}
${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES}
${MPI_LIBRARIES}
${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)

add_executable(openfastcpp src/FAST_Prog.cpp)
target_link_libraries(openfastcpp openfastcpplib
  ${MPI_LIBRARIES}
  ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES}
  ${HDF5_C_LIBRARIES}
  ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES}
  ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
  ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES}
  ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

if (OPENMP)
  find_package(OpenMP)
  if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(openfastcpplib OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
    target_link_libraries(openfastcpp OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
  endif()
endif(OPENMP)

if(MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(openfastcpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endif(MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS)

if(MPI_LINK_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(openfastcpp PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_LINK_FLAGS}")
endif(MPI_LINK_FLAGS)

set_property(TARGET openfastcpp PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

install(TARGETS openfastcpplib
  EXPORT "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Libraries"
  RUNTIME DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

install(FILES
  src/OpenFAST.H src/SC.h
  DESTINATION include)

install(TARGETS openfastcpp
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

It uses the modern OpenMP cmake invocations:

```
if (OPENMP)
  find_package(OpenMP)
  if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(openfastcpplib OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
    target_link_libraries(openfastcpp OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
  endif()
endif(OPENMP)
```

But when I build the program, I receive an error like this:

```
[ 95%] Linking CXX executable openfast_cpp
cd /home/rcrozier/build/openfast-reos-git/glue-codes/openfast/glue-codes/openfast && /snap/cmake/1210/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/openfast_cpp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/bin/c++  -fpic -O3 -DNDEBUG -rdynamic CMakeFiles/openfast_cpp.dir/src/FAST_Prog.cpp.o CMakeFiles/openfast_cpp.dir/src/FastLibAPI.cpp.o -o openfast_cpp  -Wl,-rpath,:::::::::::::: ../../modules/openfast-library/libopenfastlib.a ../../dependencies/src/lapack-build/lib/liblapack.a ../../dependencies/src/lapack-build/lib/libblas.a -ldl -lgfortran -lquadmath 
/bin/ld: ../../modules/openfast-library/libopenfastlib.a(VersionInfo.f90.o): in function `__versioninfo_MOD_dispcompileruntimeinfo._omp_fn.0':
VersionInfo.f90:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num_'
/bin/ld: VersionInfo.f90:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads_'
/bin/ld: VersionInfo.f90:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads_'
/bin/ld: ../../modules/openfast-library/libopenfastlib.a(VersionInfo.f90.o): in function `__versioninfo_MOD_dispcompileruntimeinfo':
VersionInfo.f90:(.text+0x847): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
```

If I copy the command, but manually add the `-fopenmp` option, it seems to work, there is no error message

```
cd /home/rcrozier/build/openfast-reos-git/glue-codes/openfast/glue-codes/openfast && /snap/cmake/1210/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/openfast_cpp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/bin/c++  -fpic -O3 -DNDEBUG -rdynamic CMakeFiles/openfast_cpp.dir/src/FAST_Prog.cpp.o CMakeFiles/openfast_cpp.dir/src/FastLibAPI.cpp.o -o openfast_cpp  -Wl,-rpath,:::::::::::::: ../../modules/openfast-library/libopenfastlib.a ../../dependencies/src/lapack-build/lib/liblapack.a ../../dependencies/src/lapack-build/lib/libblas.a -ldl -lgfortran -lquadmath -fopenmp
```

So my question is, assuming the `-fopenmp` is needed, and there is not some other issue I don't understand, how do I best get the `-fopenmp` option added by cmake?

**EDIT with further information**

I forgot to mention I am building static libraries, using `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`.

The cmake command I am using to generate is the following:

```
cmake -LH /home/rcrozier/src/openfast-reos-git -DBUILD_FASTFARM=ON -DBUILD_OPENFAST_CPP_API=ON -DBUILD_OPENFAST_SIMULINK_API=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DDOUBLE_PRECISION=ON -DOPENMP=ON -DUSE_LOCAL_STATIC_LAPACK=ON
```

I build out of tree in a different  directory from the source directory.

I have attempted the following fixes:

1. I added the `REQUIRED` potion to `find_package` to ensure OpenMP is available (it is)
2. adding `-fopenmp` to target_link_libraries (the [cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) state that link flags can be passed this way)

   target_link_libraries(openfastcpplib "-fopenmp")
   target_link_libraries(openfastcpp "-fopenmp")
3. adding  `-fopenmp` to `target_link_options`

   target_link_options(openfastcpplib PUBLIC "-fopenmp")
   target_link_options(openfastcpp PUBLIC "-fopenmp")
4. using `set_property`

   set_property(TARGET openfastcpp APPEND PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS "-fopenmp")
   set_property(TARGET openfastcpp APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-fopenmp")
5. using STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS as I am building with shared libraries disabled

   set_property (TARGET openfastcpp APPEND PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS  "-fopenmp")

I also used `message` to see if the flag is ever added in the following places

```
message(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS="${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS}")
message(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
message(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

It is not

6. using `target_link_options` only

   target_link_options(openfastcpp PUBLIC "-fopenmp")

7 using `target_link_options` and `target_compile_options`

```
target_compile_options(openfastcpp PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-std=c++14>)
target_link_options(openfastcpp PUBLIC "-fopenmp")
```

TRYING NOW WILL EDIT Q WITH RESULTS

Not one of the above has added linker commands where necessary.

I also noticed that there was a cmake github issue which seems to describe a similar problem [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21818). Unfortuantely the discussion is rather advanced I'm not sure if it is supposed to be fixed in cmake 3.25.1, or how to implement a workaround in my case in the same way described in the link.

Comment: OT: You may want to change `find_package(OpenMP)` to `find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)` to make sure that if OpenMP does not exist that CMake complains and makes it a fatal error.

Comment: In my experience this problem is clang specific. With gcc it works out of the box. This also seems to be a long standing issue, as there are several questions on SO about this, but not a single one has a really satisfactory answer.

Comment: @paleonix I'm not using clang, I'm using gcc and gfortran

Comment: I must have dreamed that part up. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First I will assume that you generate your cmake files with the `-DOPENMP` project as the code itself suggests it's needed and even the [documentation here](https://openfast.readthedocs.io/en/main/source/install/index.html#compile-from-source) mentions it in the section **OpenFAST CMake options**.

Secondly I would make sure as **dreschejrm pointed out**, that OpenMP is trully linked against and found correctly, I would assume this option is part of the `OpenMP` alias that you are using (i.e. `OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX`). But it might not (maybe you are using an older version or maybe it's something else very specific)

If you've checked **all of the above** and you are in the same situation then read further:

So to answer your question on how to quickly **add the option to your build,** you have a minimum of 2 ways on how to do this and one of them you are already using in the provided `CMakeLists.txt`.

1. [set_target_properties()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) - Which requires you to specify which property (e.g. `LINK_FLAGS`, `COMPILE_FLAGS`, etc.) You are for example using it in here:

```
if(MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(openfastcpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endif(MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS)

if(MPI_LINK_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(openfastcpp PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_LINK_FLAGS}")
endif(MPI_LINK_FLAGS)
```

2. [target_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) or [target_link_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html), e.g. (exempli gratia):

```
target_compile_options(openfastcpp PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-std=c++14>)

target_link_options(openfastcpp PUBLIC "-fopenmp")
```

**Please note that the above are just examples i.e. DO NOT JUST COPY PASTE THEM**. The `target_link_options/target_compile_options` are guaranteed to just add an option (and not replace the already specified ones). I am not 100% sure about the `set_target_properties` as I've never used it for `COMPILE_FLAGS/LINK_FLAGS`.

EDIT: I will state again that the above was just an example. You need to (most likely) add the linker options to `openfastlib` target as well.

In regards to the github issue they are in essence doing exactly as I'm telling you here, i.e. manually adding the linker option. If you wish to use their solution you need to update your `FindOpenMP.cmake` file with the commit that one of the people posted there. It may seem "more complicated" than what I'm explaining here but it is the exact same.

```
set_target_properties(OpenMP::OpenMP_${LANG} PROPERTIES
      INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:${LANG}>:${_OpenMP_${LANG}_OPTIONS}>"
      INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:${LANG}>:${_OpenMP_${LANG}_OPTIONS}>")
```

To explain the above snippet: `${LANG}` is just a variable representing one of the languages supported by this `.cmake` file. In your case it expands to `CXX`. The `"$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:${LANG}>:${_OpenMP_${LANG}_OPTIONS}>"` is a generator expression that is dependent on the selected language. I.e. if `COMPILE_LANGUAGE` is `CXX` it will use the specified variable `${_OpenMP_CXX_OPTIONS}` in place, etc.

They populate the specified targets which are: `INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS` and `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`. That means that instead of the `PUBLIC` keyword in `target_link_options` you should use `INTERFACE`.

Also I will repeat this again, you need to specify these options for both `openfast` and `openfastlib` targets. i.e. you need the following lines:

```
target_link_options(openfastcpplib INTERFACE "-fopenmp")
target_link_options(openfastcpp INTERFACE "-fopenmp")
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I'm not having much luck with your suggestions, I've added some info to my answer to show what I have tried.

Comment: @crobar you've added `target_link_options` only to `openfastcpp` but not `openfastcpplib` also the `target_link_libraries` is only for libraries and not link options IIRC. Can you see if adding it to both targets helps? The initial error mentions the undefined reference in `libopenfastcpplib.a` - hence why the `openfastcpplib` target requires it.

Comment: @cronbar I've updated my answer to explain exactly what the issue talks about (it is the same thing that I'm mentioning here). Also please read the entire post. What I provided you were examples of the usage of the `CMake` functions/commands. Not what you should copy paste.

Comment: Thanks for adding further information. I appreciate it is not just for me to copy and paste, and sorry I missed to also add it to the other library. However, adding both makes no difference. Regarding your comment about `target_link_libraries` the [cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) state that it can also be used to specify link flags, which is why I tried it. I'll update the question to explain that. It is not, however, the modern way to add link flags. Either way neither works.

Comment: @cronbar have you cleaned the build directory? i.e. removed it? If yes, have you tried the improved FindOpenMP.cmake? Please note that just running cmake might not be enough to propagate changes and a clean build directory might be needed.

Comment: Before each test I completely obliterated the build directory with `rm -r ./*` I haven't yet tried the improved FindOpenMP.cmake, next test.

Comment: I tried using the new version of FindOpenMP.cmake from [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/f91e48b6ae3fb40c5447c2b10c0d86f15b3f0c32/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake), by putting it in the local cmake files dir, however this failed due to a problem finding includes. I can't edit the installed version, as it's a snap mounted in a read-only file system. However, I don't see this as a viable solution anyway, since this is an open project and users can't be expected to modify their cmake files to build it.

Comment: @crobar the `FindXYZ.cmake` files unlike `XYZconfig.cmake` files are made for especially such situations. They do not know of the specific path to which you installed, they usually rely on trying to "find" the package as the name of the file suggests. Including it with your project is perfectly fine practice. However it makes sense that this file won't find the includes due to the fact that you have it on a snap mounted file system. You somehow need to change the `hints` and `paths` the `FindXYZ.cmake` uses, to point to the snap dir (ideally through a user set variable).

Comment: However that alone is already an extra step that in my opinion shouldn't be needed. Try printing out the LINK options trough out the project to see if they are by any chance overwritten by something else (like for example `target_link_libraries()`)

Comment: @crobar also, although not ideal, you can try and `set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS ...)` to see if it gets passed this way to the linker. However this solution is not ideal. See [CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS.html)
Or CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS depending on if you are statically "archiving" objects or linking a shared object